# Just how subjective can we get?

Tags: discussion

How subjective are we wanting BCG to be?

For example: [Longest Game Session](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/96/longest-game-session) is a type of question I find to be far too subjective (it's almost a poll). It also falls on the wrong side of [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) in my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging from `gaming.stackexchange.com`, game recommendations will be a frequent question type despite being fairly subjective, especially "What are some other games like X".

Gaming calls those on-topic and I think we should too, although those questions should be community wiki.

For a subjective question to be worthwhile, I think the voting has to mean *something*.  In the case of game recommendations, it means "oh yeah, I love this one too", but for others (like Longest Game Session) it's meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

Game recommendation lists are *useful* and should be on-topic on this site IMHO, just as they are on [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

I voted to close the post mentioned above not only because it was chatty and more suited to a discussion board, rather than Q&A site, but also because even if it was answered, it would not in any way enrich the site or the members experience of it. It *wasn't useful*.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your example is on the bad side of too subjective. The point here is to talk about the games themselves, not take polls on subjects like people's favorite games or tell stories about a fondly (or painfully) remembered long session.

That said, a community wiki about what kinds of games people would recommend and why might not be a bad idea. Thoughts?